# Meaning of "stuck in a barb wire snare"

Tags: expressions

What is the meaning of the expression *stuck in a barb wire snare*? I heard it in a song but I can't find the explanation and I can't figure out what it means.

Comment: Sylvia Plath used the phrase in her poem "Daddy" (written in 1962). There are lots of analyses available for that poem.

Comment: Ever since [***barbed wire***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbed_wire#The_1873_meeting_and_initial_development) was first mass-produced in the late 1870s, the form ***barb wire*** has [always been vanishingly rare](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=barb+wire%2Cbarbed+wire&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about song lyrics

Comment: Unless the song means that someone is literally caught in a snare made of barbed wire, I'd hazard a guess that it's some sort of symbolic and/or emotional snare - and since it's "made" of barbed wire, it means you'll get hurt worse (or end up scarred) trying to free yourself from the snare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *snare* is a small wire noose used for trapping wild animals.

*Barb wire* (or *barbed wire*) is a twisted wire with sharp points (barbs) sticking out from it, typically used for fencing in livestock.

To be stuck in a snare of barbed wire would be most unpleasant, as not only are you trapped in a noose, but one that is jabbing painfully into you.